# window.open returns null or undefined in edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

i am doing some operation with the window object returned from open method.
in all other browsers it is working even in other IE browsers but not working in edge browser,can any one please tell me the reason for this and provide solution

this is the code that i have written

```
var mywindow= window.open(url,'test', '_blank');
if ((mywindow== null||typeof(mywindow) == "undefined")
{
  //here i am  showing alert                
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code used for "some operation" ?

Comment: var window   = window.open(url,'test', '_blank');
     if ((window == null)
      || (typeof(window) == "undefined")
      || ) {
     
      //here we are doing some operation
     
     }

Comment: Edit your question and paste this code as "Code" into it please.

Comment: Change your variable name. I sense a scope confliction.

Comment: Is Edge currently configured to *block popups*? Is this code being called apart from a user-action, thus being mistaken for an unwanted popup? Can you upload a reproduction of the issue to the web, for direct access?

Comment: no, Edge is not configured to block popups and it is called from onpageload

Comment: Another question on the similar lines (Edge browser) - I am setting a parameter (XMLDocument object) as a custome argument to the mywindow object. But I am unable to serializetostring in the popup window. Can any one help?

Comment: Is your URL on the same server as the calling page? It seems as if Edge is extremely picky regarding Cross-Site requests. In all browsers except Edge, authentication against Azure (calling the microsoft server url) is possible in a popup.